# How to fix opengl.dll error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl

can someone help me with this error!
"The PROGRAM CANT START because OPENGL.DLL is missing from your system."

I already put the h. and .dll files in the specific directories. i'm working on a 64 bit window 7. microsoft visual c++.

Comment: Have you tried System File Checker?

Answer (score 2):

Most systems already have OPENGL.DLL in the Windows System directory.

The way to diagnose this error is to run Dependency Walker ([download here)](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Run it and open up your .EXE file - and it will tell you specifically what DLL it can't locate, or which is loaded but is not compatible.

Comment: in Dependency walker - is it the app itself, or another DLL that is trying to load OpenGL.DLL? If it is another DLL, what is that, and where is it in the filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

> OPENGL.DLL

You are sure about that name. Wasn't it opengl32.dll?

> I already put the h. and .dll files in the specific directories

Never(**!**) do this with opengl32.dll. This is a system DLL and must not be overridden by shipping one own's with the program. If you do this, you may very likely end up with not getting HW acceleration.

Comment: it wasn't opengl32.dll, just opengl.dlli just added the glut32.dll, the glut.h .

Comment: @Donnovan: If it was just opengl.dll, then this was not a system library. My best guess would be, that DLL contains some OpenGL specific module of the main program. Reinstall your program from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and discovered that I had deleted the following line before pasting the test code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
```

Make sure you have the line as above before pasting the test code.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could go to one of your friends , and copy this .dll file from his system dictionary